# optimise / shorten a TypeScript generic function to map payload to a resource based on the payload

Tags: typescript

I have been trying going through some of our code-base and I found a function that I believe I could improve on, especially that there is A LOT of repetition inside...

The function is to return a Resource based on a payload passed as a parameter. The problem is that while we have many different Payload <-> Resource pairs, the generation / mapping of the resource object does not change. So I believe we could remove a lot of the duplication in the return statements as they are ALWAYS the same.

Question:
How can I shorten this function so it removes all of the duplication of code without actually casting to a specific type (e.g. `as AResource`)

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgQQGdDh4BvAKDjimEwBMIkAbAT0XoC45CYpkA5gG4qNOoxbswmWigCSXHn0EiAvhVCRYiFGiy4CxUnKToIcStVoMmbDt178kw0dYl2wUCADcE9NNyYSKxqFBTIqBg4eABiCMzAAAqYrMwQDBau4rbsSJgAtsAOys6hFDCsYLHxeAC8hiQwJmZwAD4WSpgwAK6E3ADk3WBpDIL9cKoiGuDQ8BF60QQASsCEEN1QBpZiNpL2Sk4uVtl7FVUD%20P0ix7t29F2Y3Ns37uzoNdxxCdfUO69w9AQhGGKQAcgUigcVKJJhR1NMtHNdFEDPgVmsNrhkql0vRMi8cvtHNCCadKpD%20pcfm5CfcYI98b8aXt3glPjVsSN6D9SXcgSDWODCsVDj9YfCEbMdJF9HgAELo9abPDbZl2Pwikl-QnQfxQTWlLK3dhnClyq5G-50hnPbUsj5wL7AHl2uwY5UGo4TMqaKXzFHyxWYpIpLmMtXsDVQw289i6gLRr0RuCmgbm6knO4PJ6iWNwVmQp2c3Eu5Pu3CesVlAD01bgoCBMEEcAA7tAANbN9DdJDYJtMCjd3v9pBwASkIPKmJefLFhgAClE0hxDG4aNWSqxodxABpRJgjDA14eKABKNeT3AiId9hBMMcTjfB6cQWfbhdL9%20KBVP5Vz%20h7tQB6NMejRntwP7ls6g49re97jjAl7AC%20b4rvQAA8AAq9YgKgSD0IQyy-luaFtHAkGbiGaEAHyLtQy5ctwmGAXAwGkKBpDgURUFkRRwZkT2-jvEgwB4tstZwHIrbrMweLMAg7Z4DA5jYNYqApgAFngtA8fJimaUCO5jgg3jAKOMAaV0ml4PkmBgGAzZtlA7aEaAOAwHYFl4IQEKiBJ2BMLwYhQdwACacD1OJda-HAAB08UMbufnRb8UaJQwsV%20LFtAgrg879Kg%20RgAAtP0Rn9Gk2CYMwpWnixEkxdaObUA1MW-PFsXpfQsXWvVKVtfmDpRQNI1RgABgAJGQbEwJ1MhmU09CqNWU0zZlS1jX1I0DZ4Ph%20Am-RrIUiReL4eplcl20TFtMWqFtsKiAg6BwPOXWxaaEW1PUlL9KejLHD0UCjra1AdV1LExWlX7rdlwC5cA%20WFSVZVwBVEBVTVv0Q78TX-W1YPQ71uZtQWzVXeNq2HnNsiLctlONOtqibcTO2nft%20qo0dSRs%20d2O3Xz13E7C1CqPWzAkIgz2vdDH1fd95p-batCA8DLNxQlX4C1DaEwzlzDRIjwBFaV5WVdVtUC7jIPtRrOtE9tpN4wNFPTVT0g0wodOuwzfhMwLMW7WdB1cyde282rIsC3dQtimEAMbEgNZ1nwJrmLZ%20kIPACTEGIVRNk2pkwcOd6jghSEof%20oLAC2dFwF1F7EVRXIsTNHEwFx65QdesEjg%20iGNxXX5VzXn5oRBSH-i3h5t1xfHKt3xfwY%20UGD2hw9YTheEEdxlH-rxE%20a3A4WgFvhGd5R%20%20NxFcDYSfZnb3PJFhgA-ORSFwExm-32fB%20ka-5-8W4CJUyUBaKj0YjfKeIEGicXPDvfi7RH54HaIJYAwlRKMgklJNs3RZJwD0kpFSaklJaWChfAhBlCBGQECZMymkrJeTgLZeyjkOyuRAO5TypCfKFFEAFJAQUdKUTCtfa2BM0Ja0UG9LKesDYFSNsjU26NzZYzVlbCONs5p2weP7X4jtrbbRdmtd2C1PYrW9qQRmzMrptUDuzAYIceZoAujY6OA03HejjnACST0XpvVll9VGlw4AADIQlkODO9ckn1vqXEVpdeOQMInz0uqLYA4s8C%20OljrAJ8txhhOSbgKJVQYmowVpglKysE6FOgi1Os8JEmjiEcGMoFAJKoF4IIMI-CgqtxgfASKj1FD9AAIwACYADMAAWAArC4uu815DDIAJwAA4ADsAA2OZe51A9PgF1fADcoJ70GdQKM-RDnzNTEE%20Z6jGr8n1oKCEAwrnY30WrPIwpUaHNigAKzAAIfoQsYRwgoPshZaE5Tj0bqcxkFyurmhYvGDm-QDzYGueSNMdzsx4xCj8r8cooLzOoB8gaXyKSIv%20YC4Ft1QXwghc05U%20Br5lwHjOf82SuT4CMjNU8QhvF1gAPIAGk4AAEJ4HKnBYFeATLcBylZcvSiq8uRctxHKXlh5%20WCrgKKiVb9G7dNlTU-AYylX9xXhyoe1d1UMB5axbVAqJIAOlYyxucpzX1DZVa18ldbWIq1Y0HVEkkFAA)

So my current function looks something like this

```ts
function getResourceFromPayload(
  payload: AResourcePayload,
  asset: Asset
): AResource;
function getResourceFromPayload(
  payload: BResourcePayload,
  asset: Asset
): BResource;
function getResourceFromPayload<T extends AResourcePayload | BResourcePayload>(
  payload: T,
  asset: Asset
): AResource | BResource | undefined {

  if (payload.type === 'A') {
    // the return object generation logic is always the same
    return {
      ...payload,
      id: payload.id.replace('temp-', 'local-'),
      data: {
        ...payload.data,
        file: {
          id: `${asset.parentId}/${asset.id}`,
          provider: 'someProvider',
        },
      },
    };
  } else if (payload.type === 'B') {
    // as you can see the return object mapping/generation is the same
    return {
      ...payload,
      id: payload.id.replace('temp-', 'local-'),
      data: {
        ...payload.data,
        file: {
          id: `${asset.parentId}/${asset.id}`,
          provider: 'someProvider',
        },
      },
    };
  }
  // else if type C, and so on... there is many payloads/resources
  // and so on...

  return;
}
```

I have been trying to do something along these lines:

```ts
// try to make it less repetitive
function getResourceFromPayloadNew(
  payload: AResourcePayload,
  asset: Asset
): AResource;
function getResourceFromPayloadNew(
  payload: BResourcePayload,
  asset: Asset
): BResource;
function getResourceFromPayloadNew<T extends AResourcePayload | BResourcePayload, Y extends AResource | BResource = T extends BResourcePayload ? BResource : T extends AResourcePayload ? AResource : never>(
  payload: T,
  asset: Asset
): AResource | BResource | undefined {
  // I would like to create the resource like this, given that the mapping works exactly the same // Typescript doesn't like it
  const resource: Y = {
      ...payload,
      id: payload.id.replace('temp-', 'local-'),
      data: {
          ...payload.data,
          file: {
              id: `${asset.parentId}/${asset.id}`,
              provider: 'someProvider',
          },
      },
  };

  return resource;
}
```

but I have been getting an error when I try to create the resource as a generic type

```
Type 'T & { id: string; data: { file: { id: string; provider: string; }; displayName: string; } | { file: { id: string; provider: string; }; source: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'Y'.
  'Y' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'T & { id: string; data: { file: { id: string; provider: string; }; displayName: string; } | { file: { id: string; provider: string; }; source: string; }; }'.
```

Comment: Please make sure that your code doesn't contain any other error apart from the one that you are trying to solve. Currently your code snippet has many things missing

Comment: [This approach](https://tsplay.dev/mAgnkw) is the closest I can get.  Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer (after you [edit] the question to include all your example code in plaintext in the question and not only at a playground link); if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz the I would need to keep the types / interfaces as they are, If I replaced them with `Resource<A>` and `ResourcePayload<A>` it would mean a lot of re-factoring work across the entire application, and probably not what I was looking for

Comment: Wait, why would you need to refactor elsewhere? You could either make the old type names aliases of the generic ones, or leave your old types alone and use them (structural compatibility should make that work fine). I’ll share a playground link showing what I mean when I get to a real computer, probably after I sleep (bedtime now in my time zone).

Comment: Okay, [look at this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/N7zbDw).  I've left your type definitions and variable annotations alone and it still works.  Does that address your concerns about refactoring across the whole application?  Or am I still missing something here?